# UIActivityIndicatorView for an UIImage that load for an URL

Tags: iphone, xcode, url, uiimage, uiactivityindicatorview

I have an `UIImage` that is loaded from a URL, and i want to show an `UIActivityIndicatorView` animating while the image loads. Someone can help me?

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So u want to use the `UIActivityIndicator` while accessing the server.

First create the indicator while the connection call, and when connection didfinishloading remove the activity indicator

```
//call this when connection start
UIActivityIndicator *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(140, 236, 37, 37);
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
[self.view addSubview:activityIndicator];
self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

//remove activity indicator while connection did finish loadin
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}
```

Comment: @AlbertoJuarez then how u call the url?

Answer (score 2):

First of all add Activity indicator in xib and connect object of the UIActivity Indicator.

Click "Hides when Stopped" in the xib.

Then,

```
-(void)FetchFromServer

{

NSURLRequest* updateRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"Write Your Url Here"]];

NSURLConnection* connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:updateRequest  delegate:self];

[connection start];

[activityIndicator startAnimating];

}
```

And then in the delegate,

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData: data];

myImageView.image=img;

[activityIndicator stopAnimating];

}
```